# Error running 'app', emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am consistently getting an error when I try to start the emulator in Android Studio:
'Error running 'app': The emulator process for AVD pixel_7_API_34 has terminated.'

All the answers I've found so far are outdated and I don't understand the help log well enough to sniff out the problem on my own.

My current Android Studio version is hedgehog.2023.1.1.23 for Windows, from October 17, 2023. I'm using this version due to taking a course where it was recommended.

I tried installing and uninstalling multiple versions.
I tried recreating my project multiple times.
I tried rebuilding the gradle multiple times.
I cleared the cache, cleaned the project.
I made sure the android gradle plugin fit with the gradle version.
I reinstalled android studio on a new path.

I'm at a complete loss and the help log is gibberish to me for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this behavior as well after updating to Hedgehog. There is an open issue for this in Google's Issue Tracker: [Android Studio Hedgehog doesn't start app.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/315855033)